# Unilateral Torque Constraint on the foot-ground interface

Tags: mechanism, motion, force, legged, walk

I was studying the basics of legged locomotion and came across the unilateral force and torque constraints at the foot-ground interface.

I understood the implication of the unilateral constraint on the force ( the ground can only push the foot but not pull it) but I am unable to understand what does the unilateral torque constraint translate into physically in this case. Can anyone clarify it?